# Magento create customer and force customer id

Tags: magento2, importexport

I have magento 2.4.3.

I need to do a customer migration and I should force the **entity_id** but I get this error

```
No such entity with customerId = 40
```

I tried this code:

```
$customer = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory')->create();
                    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                    $customer->setEmail($email);
                    $customer->setFirstname($cliente['nome']);
                    $customer->setLastname($cliente['cognome']);
                    $customer->setId(40);
                    $hashing = (string)rand(0,1000000000)."mnhyty47hbs";
                    $hashedPassword = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface')->getHash($hashing, true); 
                   
                    $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->save($customer, $hashedPassword);
```

How can i do that?

Comment: You need to truncate the customer table after you can achieve this, Error is coming because ID is a primary key and it's unique values. If you want to set your ID, so you need to move the already existing customer to a new id.

Comment: Hi, i don't understand, my table of customer "customer_entity" has not a customer with entity_id=40. I want  to create a new one with entity_id = 40